# Get an array of strings from an array of objects with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js, javascript-objects

What is the best way to get an array of strings from an array of objects, where you can specify to only take value x where value y=z?

Current solution:

```
    array = [{
        "Item": "A",
        "Quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "Item": "B",
        "Quantity": 7
      },
      {
        "Item": "C",
        "Quantity": 7
      },
      {
        "Item": "D",
        "Quantity": 7
      },
      {
        "Item": "E",
        "Quantity": 7
      },
      {
        "Item": "F",
        "Quantity": 1
      }
    ];
    
    let filteredValues = array.map((el) => el.Quantity === 7 && el.Item);
    
    console.log(filteredValues)
```

Expected outcome:

```
["B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Actual outcome:

```
[false, "B", "C", "D", "E", false]
```

Additional info:
using next.js / react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**Working Demo :**

```js
const array = [{
  "Item": "A",
  "Quantity": 2
},             {
  "Item": "B",
  "Quantity": 7
},             {
  "Item": "C",
  "Quantity": 7
},{
  "Item": "D",
  "Quantity": 7
},{
  "Item": "E",
  "Quantity": 7
},{
  "Item": "F",
  "Quantity": 1
}];

const filteredValues = array.filter((el) => el.Quantity === 7).map(elem => elem.Item);
    
console.log(filteredValues)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a way to make the return list one with no duplicate values?

Comment: Yes you can achieve that by using `[...new Set(filteredValues)]`

Answer (score 3):

First, do [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) and then do a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to get only the property you need.

```js
const array = [
  { Item: "A", Quantity: 2 },
  { Item: "B", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "C", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "D", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "E", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "F", Quantity: 1 },
];

let filteredValues = array
  .filter((el) => el.Quantity === 7 && el.Item)
  .map(({ Item }) => Item);

console.log(filteredValues);
```

Or, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as below.

```js
const array = [
  { Item: "A", Quantity: 2 },
  { Item: "B", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "C", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "D", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "E", Quantity: 7 },
  { Item: "F", Quantity: 1 },
];

let filteredValues = array.reduce((results, el) => {
  if (el.Quantity === 7 && el.Item) {
    results.push(el.Item);
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(filteredValues);
```

Comment: @user1898662, check this out !!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let data = [{
    "Item": "A",
    "Quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "Item": "B",
    "Quantity": 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "C",
    "Quantity": 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "D",
    "Quantity": 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "E",
    "Quantity": 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "F",
    "Quantity": 1
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  return current["Quantity"] === 7 ? accumulator.concat(current["Item"]): accumulator;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```